# The output table did not display in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I wrote an R script by using shiny app. This script should read any input CSV file and shows it on the shiny user interface as the table. I attached my code. When I run the script, I can select s CSV file, but the output table does not display. Could you please help me?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
       # tableOutput('dto')
      dataTableOutput('dto'),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  # Reactive expression with the data, in this case iris
#----------------
  output$contents <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header),
    
  })
#----------------
  
  #the extensions parameter coupled with the options list does the trick  
  output$dto <- renderDataTable(contents(), extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
  )
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser=TRUE) #now runs by default in the external browser.
```

Comment: `contents` should not be put in `output`, it's reactive meaning you always access it if unchanged, it's not being written anywhere.

Comment: Thank you, i corrected code according your comment. it does not work yet. Could you please write corrected code as the answer? thanks

Comment: Added what it should look like below

Answer (score 2):

The [principles](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/understanding-reactivity.html) of `reactivity` specify that we do not need to add reactive components to `output`. For `contents`, we simply make it `reactive` and access it whenever we need.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
?runApp
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # tableOutput('dto')
      dataTableOutput('dto'),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  # Reactive expression with the data, in this case iris
  #----------------
  contents <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    
  })
  #----------------
  
  #the extensions parameter coupled with the options list does the trick  
  output$dto <- renderDataTable(contents(), extensions = 'Buttons', 
                                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                      buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'))
  )
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser=TRUE)
```

Comment: I had to flip back and forth several times before I truly saw the key difference. For those who may not glean NelsonGon's point from the verbiage, change `output$contents <- reactive(...)` to `contents <- reactive(...)`, just remove the `output$`.